# symfony2 upgrade 2.0 > 2.3 issue with Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session

Tags: php, symfony, session, upgrade, symfony-http-foundation

Here's my custom security listener (from sym 2.0)

```
namespace mine\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session as Session;


class SecurityListener
{
    protected $security;
    protected $session;

/**
* Constructs a new instance of SecurityListener.
*
* @param SecurityContext $security The security context
* @param Session $session The session
*/
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $security, Session $session)//<-- here
    {
        //You can bring whatever you need here, but for a start this should be useful to you
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

/**
* Invoked after a successful login.
*
* @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event The event
*/
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
         //Your logic needs to go here
         //You can addRole 
         //Even persist if you want but bring the right tools to your constructor
         $security = $this->security; 

         if ($security->getToken()->getUser()->hasPlus()) {       
            $security->getToken()->getUser()->addRole('ROLE_PLUSUSER');    
         }

    }
}
```

I assume some namespace or such changed between 2.0 and 2.1 (I am trying to lift it all the way up to 2.3 at the moment) because I am thrown this error:

ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to mine\UserBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, changing the dependency to

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

did the trick. Seemed totally opposite to what the error message was saying...